# Office365 OAuth API returns error "AADSTS90093: Does not have access to consent"

Tags: azure, active-directory, office365, office365api, office365-restapi

I have an Azure app requesting the following Delegated Permissions:

- Office 365 Exchange Online (Read user profile, Read user contacts, Read user calendars and Read user mail)
- Windows Azure Active Directory (Sign in and read user profile)

So far, most users have had no major problems signing in, but I recently had a user getting an error **AADSTS90093: Does not have access to consent**.

From what I could gather this means the user's Active Directory admin has prevented them from granting access to third party apps. Am I right? If so, is there anything I can do code- or app-configuration-wise, without bothering my users or AD admins?

(I'm new to working with Azure and Office365, so please let me know if I'm way off, I honestly have no idea what I'm doing)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes that's right. There's nothing you can do to get around it, the admin has blocked the user from using OAuth.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought :)

Comment: Do you happen to know how the admin might enable the user to use OAuth?  I have a trial subscription and came across this error while logging in as an admin.

Comment: Check out https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/exchangedev/2014/06/05/managing-user-consent-for-applications-using-office-365-apis/. The Set-MsolCompanySettings cmdlet is what you're looking for.

Comment: what does the admin need to do to unblock that user?

Comment: They need to undo the block. The Powershell command is `Set-MsolCompanySettings –UsersPermissionToUserConsentToAppEnabled:$true`